# How to group adjacent numbers that are the same

Tags: ruby

I need to pack if there are at least two adjacent numbers which are same in the format `<number : number_of_occurrences >`.

This is my input:

```
[2,2,2,3,4,3,3,2,4,4,5]
```

And the expected output:

```
"2:3,3,4,3:2,2,4:2,5"
```

So far I tried:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
a.each_cons(2).any? do |s , t|
  if s == t
```

If it's equal try a counter maybe, but thats not working.

Comment: You'll obviously need to check either the number prior or the number after. Please keep trying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#`chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) (if you're on Ruby >= 2.3):

```
a.chunk_while { |a, b| a == b }
 .flat_map { |chunk| chunk.one? ? chunk.first : "#{chunk.first}:#{chunk.size}" }
 .join(',')
#=> "2:3,3,4,3:2,2,4:2,5"
```

You can also use [Enumerable#`chunk`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) (Ruby ~1.9.3, maybe earlier):

```
a.chunk(&:itself)
 .flat_map { |_, chunk| chunk.one? ? chunk.first : "#{chunk.first}:#{chunk.size}" }
 .join(',')
#=> "2:3,3,4,3:2,2,4:2,5"
```

Comment: Yes, its a string Andrey, Enumerable#chunk_while: is working great. thanks!

Comment: `a.chunk(&:itself)` is similar.

Comment: @SajeeshKrishnan n/p :) Don't forget to accept the answer if that works for you and you don't expect to see other solutions.

Comment: For `chunk`, you can write `a.chunk(&:itself).flat_map { |_,a| ... }.join(',')`. `chunk`, as opposed to `chunk_while`, should be the go-to method here, because it the simpler of the two and, whereas `chunk_while` made its debut in Ruby v2.3, `chunk` is supported by essentially all versions of Ruby. I'm not sure if `chunk_while` even deserves a mention.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're right from the Ruby versions perspective. I won't remove the `chunk_while` option from the answer though, - to me it shows the intention better.

Answer (score 3):

You could [`chunk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43586713/6419007) elements together when they're equal, you could also [`slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) the array between elements that are distinct (`slice_when` has been added in Ruby 2.2 ):

```
[2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5].slice_when { |a, b| a != b }.map do |ints|
  if ints.size == 1
    ints[0]
  else
    "#{ints[0]}:#{ints.size}"
  end
end.join(',')
# "2:3,3,4,3:2,2,4:2,5"
```

It's mostly a matter of taste, both methods can achieve perfectly similar results, just like `select` and `reject`.

Comment: There's another difference that is important if older versions of Ruby must be supported: `Enumerable#chunk` has around since the beginning of time, whereas `Enumerable#slice_when` made its debut in Ruby v2.3.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks. [2.2](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) as far as I can tell.

Comment: I sometimes mix up earliest version dates between `slice_when` (yes, 2.2) and `chunk_while` (2.3).

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5]

arr.drop(1).each_with_object([[arr.first, 1]]) do |e,a|
  a.last.first == e ? a[-1][-1] += 1 : a << [e, 1]
end.map { |a| a.join(':') }.join(',')
  #=> "2:3,3:1,4:1,3:2,2:1,4:2,5:1"
```